# How do I click on a selection menu using title only (selenium driver) JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, google-chrome

Hey I am very new to using
selenium i am using Nodejs and trying to click on a selection menu for a forum which asks for your year of birth and i wanted to automate this

Html code
Please note there are multi selection menus with the class of "_aau-" but all i ened to change is the year.
`<select class="_aau-" title="Year:"><option title="2022" value="2022">2022</option><option title="2021" value="2021">2021</option><option title="2020" value="2020">2020</option><option title="2019" value="2019">2019</option><option title="2018" value="2018">2018</option><option title="2017" value="2017">2017</option><option title="2016" value="2016">2016</option><option title="2015" value="2015">2015</option><option title="2014" value="2014">2014</option><option title="2013" value="2013">2013</option><option title="2012" value="2012">2012</option><option title="2011" value="2011">2011</option><option title="2010" value="2010">2010</option><option title="2009" value="2009">2009</option><option title="2008" value="2008">2008</option><option title="2007" value="2007">2007</option><option title="2006" value="2006">2006</option><option title="2005" value="2005">2005</option><option title="2004" value="2004">2004</option><option title="2003" value="2003">2003</option><option title="2002" value="2002">2002</option><option title="2001" value="2001">2001</option><option title="2000" value="2000">2000</option><option title="1999" value="1999">1999</option><option title="1998" value="1998">1998</option><option title="1997" value="1997">1997</option><option title="1996" value="1996">1996</option><option title="1995" value="1995">1995</option><option title="1994" value="1994">1994</option><option title="1993" value="1993">1993</option><option title="1992" value="1992">1992</option><option title="1991" value="1991">1991</option><option title="1990" value="1990">1990</option><option title="1989" value="1989">1989</option><option title="1988" value="1988">1988</option><option title="1987" value="1987">1987</option><option title="1986" value="1986">1986</option><option title="1985" value="1985">1985</option><option title="1984" value="1984">1984</option><option title="1983" value="1983">1983</option><option title="1982" value="1982">1982</option><option title="1981" value="1981">1981</option><option title="1980" value="1980">1980</option><option` 
there is more but i don't wanna flood it

i've tried differnt methood's ive seens online and none of them work
so i am asking hee for help I guess.

i've tried stuff like

`

const ageChoice = await browser.findElement(By.xpath("//select[title^='Year:']"))
await ageChoice.click()

` tryingto just even open the menu but ti always gives the error back
SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string '//select[title^='Year:']' is not a valid XPath expression. or differnt errors if i change the path and the // parts

hope you can help me I am very new to this so some code would be helpful as i coudn't really find much online info sorry to bother you guys.

Answer (score 0):

Try this XPath:

```
.//select[@class='_aau-' and @title='Year:']
```